# How to check BLAS/LAPACK linkage in NumPy and SciPy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, lapack, blas

I am builing my numpy/scipy environment based on blas and lapack more or less based on [this](http://www.tfinley.net/notes/blas-lapack/) walk through.

When I am done, how can I check, that my numpy/scipy functions really do use the previously built blas/lapack functionalities?

Answer (score 316, accepted):

The method `numpy.show_config()` (or `numpy.__config__.show()`) outputs information about linkage gathered at build time. My output looks like this. I think it means I am using the BLAS/LAPACK that ships with Mac OS.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.show_config()

lapack_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
blas_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
```

Comment: Given its widespread usefulness, `numpy.__config__` should really be a public API. Nonetheless, **you win this round, [davost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877003/davost).**

Comment: So, the mere fact that `lapack_opt_info` is shown means that numpy is linked with lapack?

Comment: How do you interpret the output?

Comment: @CecilCurry You can use `numpy.show_config()`, which is probably a public API function by virtue of the absence of starting underscores. But it's not documented online and has no docstring, so it's no surprise that it's so hard to find. Hopefully they'll fix that.

Comment: how do I find out which package is actually used when multiple packages are displayed?

Comment: @davost, how did you install `numpy`? Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I want just to know if my numpy is linked to blas so that linear algebra computation are fast enough. I get this: https://imgur.com/a/SsrDqg5. How do you interpret this?

Comment: Be careful: this information is gathered at **build time**. As BLAS and LAPACK are standard interfaces, it's possible to build against netlib's reference implementation (which is slow) while dynamically linking to the optimized OpenBLAS implementation at runtime.

Answer (score 29):

What you are searching for is this:
[system info](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/distutils/system_info.py)

I compiled numpy/scipy with atlas and i can check this with:

```
import numpy.distutils.system_info as sysinfo
sysinfo.get_info('atlas')
```

Check the documentation for more commands.

Comment: This doesn't seem to show whether numpy currently uses ATLAS, just whether ATLAS will be linked against during the next numpy compilation. I had numpy compiled before ATLAS. It worked very slow until I recompiled numpy (sure thing), but both before and after numpy recompilation sysinfo.get_info('atlas') shown the same output. How to check the current state of affairs?

Comment: How to interpret the output?

Comment: You might have 'blas' instead of 'atlas' installed (this happens if you install openblas on debian based distros).

Comment: [davost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877003/davost)'s answer should probably have been accepted in lieu of this response, which fails to address the question at hand. Since this response does uncover interesting machinery of use in solving _other_ related questions, a hearty thanks all the same!

Comment: @rabra `sysinfo.get_info('atlas')` returned nothing for me but `sysinfo.get_info('blas')` returned  
```{'include_dirs': ['/usr/local/include',  
  '/usr/include',  
  '/opt/local/include',  
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include'],  
'libraries': ['blas', 'blas'],  
'library_dirs': ['/usr/lib']}```  
and `sysinfo.get_info('lapack')` returned  
```{'language': 'f77',  
 'libraries': ['lapack', 'lapack'],  
 'library_dirs': ['/usr/lib']}```  
What does it mean ?

Comment: This returns nothing but an empty set 

Comment: This doesn't work any more, it's deprecated and returns an empty dict. At import you get the helpful message "`numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present."

Answer (score 11):

You can use the link loader dependency tool to look at the C level hook components of your build and see whether they have external dependencies on your blas and lapack of choice. I am not near a linux box right now, but on an OS X machine you can do this inside the site-packages directory which holds the installations:

```
$ otool -L numpy/core/_dotblas.so 
numpy/core/_dotblas.so:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 268.0.1)

$ otool -L scipy/linalg/flapack.so 
scipy/linalg/flapack.so (architecture i386):
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.1.4)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 242.0.0)
scipy/linalg/flapack.so (architecture ppc):
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.1.4)

$ otool -L scipy/linalg/fblas.so 
scipy/linalg/fblas.so (architecture i386):
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.1.4)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 242.0.0)
scipy/linalg/fblas.so (architecture ppc):
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.1.4)
```

substitute `ldd` in place of `otool` on a gnu/Linux system and you should get the answers you need.

Comment: What if there is no file `numpy/core/_dotblas.so` ? (see comment below Ricardos answer)

Comment: @Woltan: either something is seriously broken, or you are looking in the wrong place. On every Linux and OS X numpy install I have ever seen, there will be a `_dotblas.so` which is the interface wrapper to whatever blas has been used to build the distribution. On windows it will be called `_dotblas.pyd`, but the function is the same.

Comment: It seems like `_dotblas.so` is only built if you're using a `[atlas]` section in `site.cfg` (and a CBLAS-enabled BLAS library). So, you should use that, even if you're not using ATLAS (except when you're using Intel MKL, that has a dedicated section).

Comment: Indeed, when no BLAS is available when NumPy is built, it builds its own dot-product routines. These can be two orders of magnitude slower than ATLAS.

Comment: [`_dotblas.so` no longer exists in numpy v1.10 and newer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html#dropped-support), but you can check the linkage of `multiarray.so` instead

Comment: Here's a nice way (it seems):
`nm /path/to/numpy/core/multiarray.so | grep blas_dot`.
If there's no `blas_dot` symbol, then numpy is not linked against BLAS (for v1.10 and up)

Answer (score 9):

You can display BLAS, LAPACK, MKL linkage using `show_config()`:

```
import numpy as np
np.show_config()
```

Which for me gives output:

```
mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/my/environment/path/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/my/environment/path/include']
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/my/environment/path/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/my/environment/path/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/my/environment/path/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/my/environment/path/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/my/environment/path/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/my/environment/path/include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/my/environment/path/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/my/environment/path/include']
```

Comment: How do you interpret `('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]`?

Comment: @serafeim See [link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/extension.py#L37). It essentially means that `HAVE_CBLAS` is being defined but has no value (think C: `#define HAVE_CBLAS`). It does not need a value as it is only used as a flag. I would interpret it as `HAVE_CBLAS=True`. If you did not have CBLAS, you would not have the tuple there at all.

Comment: I want just to know if my numpy is linked to blas so that linear algebra computation are fast enough. I get this: https://imgur.com/a/SsrDqg5. How do you interpret this?

Comment: @makis numpy is linked to openblas

Answer (score -2):

If you installed anaconda-navigator (at www.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/ for linux, Windows or macOS) - blas, scipy and numpy will all be installed and you can see them by clicking environments tab on left side of navigator home page (look for each directory in alpha order). Installing full anaconda (as opposed to miniconda or individual packages) will take care of installing many of the essential packages needed for data science.