# Unintended multithreading in Python (scikit-learn)

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn

I'm using mixture submodule of sklearn module for Gaussian Mixture Model... When I run my code on a multicore system, it uses multiple cores even though I do not ask for it in the code. Is this a default behavior? And more important, how can I disable it?

Thanks

Comment: is it possible that your numpy installation is multithreaded?

Comment: hmmm. maybe. how can I check it? and how can I force it to be single threaded without reinstalling?

Comment: try multiplying 2 giant matrices (A.dot(B) not A * B), like 5000x5000, and see if there's multi core usage. The multithreading depends on the library your numpy was compiled against.

Comment: Ok, you are right. I've tried what you recommended and it runs on multi cores. Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Comment: how did you install your numpy library? check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053671/python-how-do-you-stop-numpy-from-multithreading

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using MKL then try

`export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1`

For Numpy with OpenBLAS:

`export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1`

For some versions of Numpy this variation has been suggested:

`export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=1`

The environment variable has to be set before the script is run (setting inside the script itself does not have the desired effect). For setting threads at runtime see: [Set max number of threads at runtime on numpy/openblas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559338/set-max-number-of-threads-at-runtime-on-numpy-openblas)

See the following for identifying how your numpy is setup: [How to check blas/lapack linkage in numpy/scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000164/how-to-check-blas-lapack-linkage-in-numpy-scipy)

Answer (score 1):

thanks @prgao

the answer is there [Python: How do you stop numpy from multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053671/python-how-do-you-stop-numpy-from-multithreading)

setting "export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1" seems to be working

Comment: It works only if the version of numpy use use is linked against the MKL implementation of BLAS / LAPACK. For OpenBLAS, it is going to be `export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1` instead. For ATLAS you will have to recompile ATLAS to disable threading.

Comment: Thanx we were going crazy!