# RandomForestClassifier.fit uses different amount of RAM on different machines

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

for some reason `RandomForestClassifier.fit` from `sklearn.ensemble` uses only 2.5GB RAM on my local machine but almost 7GB on my server with absolutely same training set.

The code without imports is pretty much this:

```
y_train = data_train['train_column']
x_train = data_train.drop('train_column', axis=1)

# Difference in memory consuming starts here
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
clf = clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
preds = clf.predict(data_test)
```

My local machine is macbook pro with 16GB of memory and 4 core CPU
My server is Ubuntu server on digitalocean cloud with 8 GB of memory and 4 core CPU too.

Version of sklearn is 0.18, Python version is 3.5.2

I can't even imagine possible reasons, any help will be very helpful.

**UPDATE**

Memory Error appears in this code inside the `fit` method:

```
# Parallel loop: we use the threading backend as the Cython code
# for fitting the trees is internally releasing the Python GIL
# making threading always more efficient than multiprocessing in
# that case.
trees = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose,
                 backend="threading")(
    delayed(_parallel_build_trees)(
        t, self, X, y, sample_weight, i, len(trees),
        verbose=self.verbose, class_weight=self.class_weight)
    for i, t in enumerate(trees))
```

**UPDATE 2**

Informaiton about my systems:

```
# local
Darwin-16.1.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct 11 2016, 05:05:28)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)]
NumPy 1.11.2
SciPy 0.18.1
Scikit-Learn 0.18

# server
Linux-3.13.0-57-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec 18 2015, 00:00:00)
[GCC 4.8.4]
NumPy 1.11.2
SciPy 0.18.1
Scikit-Learn 0.18
```

Also my numpy configs:

```
# server
>>> np.__config__.show()
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c


# local
>>> np.__config__.show()
blas_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Repr of `clf` object is the same on both machines:

```
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
            min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=42,
            verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that you probably have very different BLAS, LAPACK, and other C libraries installed on your Macbook compared to your VPS. Falling back on a different algorithm (or even a different implementation of the same algorithm) to compute something used when fitting a model to your data could certainly explain the memory blow up. The first place to look is at your [numpy information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9002656/2503352) on the respective systems.

Comment: Hm, my numpy is the same on both machines. The only significant difference is GCC as I see.

Comment: It's not the version of numpy itself, but the libraries numpy is compiled against that's likely to be at play here. It may also be that difference in GCC versions.

Comment: I got it, just updated question with it

Comment: The big difference I see is that your Ubuntu libraries weren't compiled against SSE3 and your Apple libraries are compiled against a couple of their libraries. SSE3 causing memory usage blow up seems dubious to me, though I'm not an expert in this field. The Apple libraries I'm not familiar with, but I could see being responsible for the problem.

Comment: The thing is that on mac it shows great result on RAM and it blows only on server. May be I should try to rebuild numpy with same libraries as on mac if it's even possible. It could be some proprietary libraries.

Comment: could you print your RandomForestClassifier object on both machines before calling fit?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, issue magically gone after I updated kernel from `3.13.0-57` to `4.4.0-28`. Now it eats even less memory than my local mac laptop.

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is that your server uses older scikit-learn. it was an issue while ago that sklearn RF was extremely memory hungry, which has been fixed in 0.17 if I recall correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I use same versions of scikit-learn, scipy and numpy. I'll update my question with this info

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the reason, but OS X has memory compression enabled by default; on Linux zRam / zswap / zcache are optional and not default (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory_compression).