# Scikit-learn machine learning models training using multiple CPUs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

I want to decrease training time of my models by using a high end EC2 instance. So I tried `c5.18xlarge` instance with 2 CPUs and run a few models with parameter `n_jobs=-1` but I noticed that only one CPU was utilized:

[image]

Can I somehow make Scikit-learn to use all CPUs?

Comment: MWE... all that jazz... you should know better given your rep. That being said, as a first pass, I would [make sure that you have compiled numpy with a linear algebra library that actually supports multi-core processing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000164/how-to-check-blas-lapack-linkage-in-numpy-scipy)

Comment: @PaulBrodersen I have `numpy` linked to `BLAS`, I hope you understood that it's not about multi-core processing but about multi-cpu processing, my first CPU does the job perfectly fine but the second one is idle.

Comment: Try adding `import multiprocessing; multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver');` at the top of your code, before running or importing anything.. Does it solve the issue?

Comment: @QusaiAlothman It worked! Could you post the advice as the answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver')
```

at the top of your code, before running or importing anything. That's a well-known issue with multiprocessing in python.