# Does scipy.linalg.eigvals parallelize automatically?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, apple-m1

I have written a python script that sets up and solves an eigenvalue problem, using the `eigvals` function from `scipy`'s `linalg`. I haven't done any optimisation or parallelization.

When I run it, the call to `eigvals` takes about 10 seconds when nothing else computationally intensive is running.

However, when I run this script at the same time as running something big, such as a serial C++ simulation, which I'm almost certain is running on a different processor (but I don't know how to check this), the call to `eigvals` slows right down, taking five minutes or more.

My question is: does the `eigvals` call automatically try to make use of other available processors out of the box? I can't see any other reason why it would slow down if I'm running something on a different processor.

In case it's relevant, my versions are:
`scipy` 1.10.1, python 3.11, Apple M1 Pro chip, macOS Ventura 13.6.3.

Comment: Scipy should use LAPACK for that which is a standard to compute eigenvalues. LAPACK is based on BLAS libraries. There are many BLAS implementations. Mainstream ones tend to be parallel. In general, SciPy/Numpy should use OpenBLAS (which is parallel) on most platforms. As a result, the eigenvalue computation can be parallel (but not completely) on a lot of platform. You can check the linked libraries and the use of CPUs. By the way, libraries using both P-cores and E-cores can be slower than using only P-cores on some big-little CPUs (apparently not the M1-pro but possibly the M1 classic)

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add "Pro" to my chip and have edited my post to reflect this. How can I check the linked libraries and what CPUs I am using?

Comment: You can check your linked library as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000164/how-to-check-blas-lapack-linkage-in-numpy-and-scipy As for how to see if it runs parallel, just check the CPU utilization. I'm sure even Apple comes with something like a performance monitor, or `top` in a terminal

Comment: Even if the computation is serial and on a different core, two computations can still interfere if they compete for shared resources such L3 cache, main memory bandwidth, or the CPUs may run at lower clock frequencies to stay within the thermal limits of the platform compared to a single core being busy

Comment: On my 2017 MBP OSX system, with SciPy using OpenBLAS as the BLAS library, `scipy.linalg.eigvals()` uses multiple cores, according to the program `htop`.